# Slicing of list impossible after modifying __getitem__

Tags: python

For a specific use case I want to define a list class that returns 0 if an index is either negative or out of range.

My current approach is already serving the specific purpose:

```
class mlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if (len(self)<=n) or (n<0):
            return 0
        return super(mlist, self).__getitem__(n)

l = mlist([1,2,3,4])
l[-2]
>>> 0
l[10]
>>> 0
```

But unfortunately, it causes some bad behavior when slicing the list:

```
l[0:2]
>>> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'slice'
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, because you aren't handling slices. Probably, just check if `isinstance(n, slice): return super().__getitem__(n)` then continue with your current logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to suppress `IndexError` and return `0` instead. So, you could alternatively do:

```py
class mlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(n)
        except IndexError:
            return 0
```

This, however allows negative indexing (accessing from the end) as usual lists (because this does not raise an `IndexError`). If you want to suppress that as well, you might try:

```py
class mlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        try:
            if n < 0 or n >= len(self):
                return 0
            return super().__getitem__(n)
        except TypeError:
            return super().__getitem__(n)
```

This *assumes* `n` is an int and works accordingly, and if it was not, a `TypeError` will be raised on the comparison and the `super` method will be called. This, then, both handles slices and throws the appropriate error when passing an invalid type, like string for example.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the argument `n` is anything you pass between square brackets, whether is is an index (so type `int`), or a slice (of type `slice`).

Your current code only works in the case `n` is of type `int`, it does not take care of slices properly.

If you want to keep slicing functionality the same as default, why not call `super().__getitem__(n)` ?

```
class mlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        # If n is a slice
        if isinstance(n, slice):
            return super().__getitem__(n)

        # Otherwise
        if len(self)<=n or n<0:
            return 0
        return super(mlist, self).__getitem__(n)
```

However, if you want to implement your own logic for slices, you can do so inside the `if isinstance(n, slice):` block.

Comment: Explicit type-checking is unpythonic.

Comment: @martineau In this specific problem, type checking is needed, as ints and slices have to be treated differently (unless you use a try/except workaround like Tomerikoo's answer). What is a more "pythonic" way of doing that?

Comment: @martineau In this case I don't see the problem. List indices can only be ints or slices, no other types. For example even passing `Decimal(0)` as an index fails.

Comment: Anis and @wjandrea: `try...except` is the "pythonic" way.